# Enter SMTP and IMAP server parameters manually in Windows Mail

Tags: windows-10

How to enter SMTP and IMAP server parameters manually in Windows Mail? I don't see any options to change these settings.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Click **Options for syncing your content.**
2. Scroll to the bottom and
   click **Advanced mailbox settings**
3. You can then change your
   settings as desired.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is not clickable